# How to discard/TRIM a range in an open file ?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ssd, trim

For an SSD, I can open the row device and discard a range of pages using `ioctl()` with `BLKDISCARD` command.

My question is

for an open file, how to discard a range of data? and Is that depends on the implementation of the underlying filesystem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [`fallocate`'s `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html). It's then up to the filesystem to discard/trim/unmap those blocks. I believe ext4 will do so.

For example, you'd do something like this to discard 2MiB starting 1MiB in:

```c
err = fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE|FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 1048576, 2097152);
if (0 != err) {
    /* handle error */
}
```

On success, future reads of those bytes should give 0s.

[Note: POSIX doesn't have a way to do this. The above fallocate is Linux-specific. But you tagged your question Linux, so hopefully that's OK.]